# Angular Memory Leak using setInterval & observables

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, observable

I recently added this notification component to my fixed header and now I'm getting memory woes on my IIS server.  I don't think this component will ever get destroyed and I think that's the problem.  This component loads & updates notification messages from my API server every 5 secs.  I'm pretty sure I'm getting a memory leak here -- somewhere.  HELP?!

```
ngOnInit(): void
{
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() =>
    {
        this.notificationService.getAll()
            .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
            .subscribe(
                data =>
                {
                    this.notifications = data;
                    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
                    this.store.dispatch(new actions.LoadNotificationsSuccess(this.notifications));
                },
                error =>
                {
                    console.log('error', error);
                    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
                });
    }, 5000);
}

ngOnDestroy(): void
{
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsubscribing the observable from an active HTTP request cancels it. Here is a mundane implementation to cancel any impending requests before triggering a new one.

```js
apiSubscription: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.apiSubscription) {
      this.apiSubscription.unsubscribe();       // <-- cancel any impending requests
    }
    this.apiSubscription = this.notificationService.getAll()
      .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.notifications = data;
          this.cdRef.detectChanges();
          this.store.dispatch(new actions.LoadNotificationsSuccess(this.notifications));
        },
        error => {
          console.log('error', error);
          clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        });
  }, 5000);
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
```

If you have control over the API, I'd recommend you to look into [server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). They are similar to Websockets but are designed for a single way communication stream between the server and the client. You could avoid these kinds of recurring HTTP calls that could potentially accumulate over time.